# How to get OS X style App Menu?

Tags: 11.04, appmenu, macosx

How do I get the app menu to look like OSX? (Not the Global Menu, the menu items)

[image]

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 with the Classic Gnome desktop (not Unity).

Comment: Can you describe which aspects you're after? The global menu? The apple logo? The colour/transparency? Etc

Comment: The menu items, About, Update, Preferences, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this little Mac menu, just follow these steps:

1. Go up to your Menu bar or main menu and right click on it to bring up the context menu.
2. Click on Edit Menus and the menu editor should come up.
3. In the menu editor, on the right side, click the button that says "New Menu". Here's a screen:
   [image: The menu editor]
4. Add the items you want to this menu, and change the icon to whatever you want the icon to be on the panel.
5. Now, close the menu editor and open up the main menu applet, and right click on an item in the menu you made.
6. In the context menu, go to Entire Menu > Add this as menu to panel. Here's a screenshot:
   [image: The context menu]

End result: 
[image: end result]

You should now have your Apple menu-like menu.

Comment: you can and probably should attach those images to your post. There is small button for attaching images while you edit post.